# (JavaScript) Creating a more efficient algorithm than the one I had

Tags: javascript, algorithm, processing-efficiency

I have this situation :

```
    let scans = [
      { source: "10.0.0.2", destination: "20.0.0.2" }
      { source: "10.0.0.4", destination: "20.0.0.6" }
    ]

    const handleScan = (source, destination, port) => {
      let newScan = {
        source : source, 
        destination : destination
      }

      for (scan of scans) {
        if (scan.source !== source && scan.destination !== destination)
        scans.push(newScan)
      }
    }
```

Now, this function gets executed 1000 times per second, meaning a for loop everytime to see if the pair exists is very bad. 
How would you suggest me to do it more efficient?

Comment: If you have no problems with your code and it is actually working but you just want to review it and maybe improve, I think you can find a better answer asking on https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Do you really mean to only push scans where the source AND destination are different from any existing scan?

Comment: You could create a `Set` which is a combination of source and destination seperated by `|`

Comment: @adiga: That works if you push a new scan if EITHER the source OR destination is different from all existing scans; not so much if it has to be BOTH.

Comment: That pushes a lot of copies of `newScan` onto your array, which could be where your performance problems come from. If you call `handleScan` once with a previously unseen IP as the source and destination, you double the size of scans by calling `scans.push(newScan)` once for every single element already in scans. If you call it 1000 times per seconds with new IPs, `scans` will quickly take up more memory than there is in the entire universe

Comment: @ScottHunter I meant creating a set which is combination of both like this `10.0.0.2_20.0.0.2` with a `|` or `_` separator

Comment: @adiga: That doesn't address the problem.

Comment: Like @Paulpro said, your current algorithm doesn't even seem to work properly. What is your [actual problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377) that the function should solve? How is this `scans` array used elsewhere?

Comment: @adiga Hi, is creating a Set not the same processing-wise as a loop? it's not a loop behind the scenes that reduces the array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the goal to keep track of all destinations for all sources?  If so that's not what it is currently doing.  Here's how to do that:

```
let scans = [
  { source: "10.0.0.2", destination: "20.0.0.2" }
  { source: "10.0.0.4", destination: "20.0.0.6" }
]

const handleScan = (source, destination, port) => {
  let newScan = {
    source : source, 
    destination : destination
  }

  var scanFound = false;
  for (scan of scans) {
    if (scan.source !== source && scan.destination !== destination){
      scanFound = true;
      break;
    }
  }
  if(!scanFound){
    scans.push(newScan)
  }
}
```

If that IS the goal, I'd suggest altering the format to an object with source as the key and destinations as the value so it's a lookup rather than a loop:

```
var destinationsBySource = {
  "10.0.0.2": ["20.0.0.2"],
  "10.0.0.4": ["20.0.0.6"]
]

var handleScan = function(source, destination){
  //Initialize destinations as an array if source is not there
  destinationsBySource[source] = destinationsBySource[source] || [];

  //Add the destination if needed
  if(destinationsBySource[source].indexOf(destination) == -1){
    destinationsBySource[source].push(destination);
  }
};//End of handleScan function
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This is the type of solution I remembered should be in this situation, but couldn't quite do it.

Comment: @YossiDagan Welcome, glad I could help :)